# An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'ApplicationDbContext.Locations'

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

```
 public ActionResult Filter()
    {
        var viewModel = new Location();
        viewModel.Patients = ApplicationDbContext.Locations.ToList();
        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

This is in my controller, I have patients that are located at one of two locations, and I am trying to create a dropdownlist to filter between the two locations.

This is the model that I am using for it.

```
namespace FolderSystem.Models
{
    public class Location
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Address")]
        public int? AddressId { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Patient> Patients { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUsers { get; set; }
        public virtual Address Address { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is ApplicationDbContext? Is this a field or property or have you not shown the whole code? How is this field/property/variable assigned?

Comment: In my Data folder, I have ApplicaitonDbContext.cs, and I have 
'public DbSet<Location> Locations {get;set;}'
Is that what you are asking? I have ApplicationDbContext set as a class

Comment: You need to take a step back and learn the difference between a type and an instance. This is basic programming, there are many tutorials available about this. Based on your next question I also recommend you follow some tutorials on basic programming. Learning how to program by posting your errors from your IDE in [so] is not a good way to go about it.

Answer (score 1):

you must declare an object from `ApplicationDbContext` as this

```
ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
```

then you can use db instead of ApplicationDbContext as this

```
public ActionResult Filter()
{
    var viewModel = new Location();
    viewModel.Patients = db.Locations.ToList();
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but now I am getting the error, Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Gemeric.List<FolderSystem.Models.Location>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<FolderSystem.Models.Patient>'. An explicit conversion exists(are you missing a cast?)
Should I cast it? Or change the folders that are you?

Comment: I'm thinking I need to cast it somehow to convert it to a list? But I am unsure how

Comment: ok my friend,i advise you to learn object oriented in first to do not face this problems.
this your solve

public ActionResult Filter()
{
    var locations = db.Locations.ToList();
    return View(locations);